# IO buffering hanging on java program

Tags: java

We are running on the Google cloud servers running code compiled under version 1.7    As of three days ago the software was running fine, now the java programs will intermittently hang.  The software has not changed.  We can get the application to continue by doing "crtl Z" and then "bg" then "fg".  We have changed nothing in the production environment on our end.  Could Google have down something underneath us to cause the java program to have buffering issues.  These apps we are running pull data from a postgres table and write to local google disk drives.  We have already determined its not a postgres or NFS problem.  The application just hangs writing the data(we think).

The question really comes down to is there something that Google could have updated to make a java app all of sudden start to act weird?  Sorry for the vague discription, but I'm just enlisted to help with the issue and not a java programmer.   Once again, sometimes the program will work, and was working flawlessly three days ago.

Comment: Anything's possible, but there's not much we can do to help with so little detail.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I'll see if I can get one of the engineers to explain it better. Thanks.